# why am I getting AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'list'

Tags: python, api, google-api, youtube-api

ok so I'm trying to write this simple call request for YouTube channel data but it seems I'm still too much of a noob to fully understand what I'm doing wrong I understand that there is some type of syntax error but what I want to fully understand is why is there a syntax error so I can easily solve this issue in the future. I've spent too many hours trying to figure out the error here I know an experienced coder could solve this issue in a matter of minute so can someone help please.

Here is the full list of error terminal spits back

```
 line 8, in channel_list_scrape
    list_channel_attr = youtube.channels.list(id=youtube_channel).execute()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'list'

line 11, in <module>
    channel_list_scrape(youtube_channel = 'CNN')
```

**Code:**

```
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    import csv


     def channel_list_scrape(youtube_channel):
         DEVELOPER_KEY = 'string_would_go_in_here'
         youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
         list_channel_attr = youtube.channels.list(id=youtube_channel).execute()
         return(list_channel_attr)

      channel_list_scrape(youtube_channel = 'CNN')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of the api you are using, but from the traceback it sounds like you need to do something like this:

```
list_channel_attr = youtube.channels().list(id=youtube_channel).execute()
```

From what it it looks like, you want to call the `list()` method of whatever object is returned by `youtube.channels()`. What you are doing now is calling `list()` on the `youtube.channels` method object itself, rather than calling it on the object that method returns.

To further illustrate, observe the following interactive session with explanations in the comments:

```
In [1]: def foo():  # This function returns a list
   ...:     return [1, 2, 3]
   ...:     
   ...: 

In [2]: [1, 2, 3].pop()  # lists have a pop method
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: foo().pop()  # so the return value of the function also has a pop method
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: foo.pop()  # but the function itself does not have a pop method
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-20ec23cbc1ac> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.pop()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Comment: I am humbled,  you guys are godsends ok you seem to be on the right track now I am getting the error

/Users/Username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 716, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "part"

Comment: @edgent7 what line in your code is raising the error? Please post the full traceback to your original question. Thanks!

Comment: @edgent7 it looks like `youtube.channels.list()` needs a `part` argument, but I have not been able to find the documentation that explains what this is.

Comment: yeah, figured it out and got the whole thing working it was missing required parameters for the list method, actually the function I needed to use was the search().list method because i am trying to retrieve youtube tags data from a channel to then store in a csv file. for anybody who runs into this problem check this out

Comment: for anybody who runs into this problem check this out

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list 

the example section python